# Takens’ embedding theorem for multistable systems

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

In an informal way, Takens’ theorem states, that we can reconstruct a (chaotic) attractor of an $N$-dimensional dynamical system with a delay embedding of just one trajectory $x_i(t)$:

$(x_i(t),x_i(t-\tau),...,x_i(t-k \cdot \tau))$

for some $k \geq 2d$ has equivalent dynamics to

$(x_1(t),...,x_d(t))$.

Suppose we have a multistable dynamical system with e.g. two (chaotic) attractors. If we sample the trajectory on one attractor, can we recover the other one by delayed embedding?

Is there some known generalization of Takens’ theorem to multistable systems?

Comment: I think it can be helpful if you cite the formal statement of the Theorem and, e.g., give an example of a system with two chaotic attractors. Then we can check if it fits the theorem or if there is a violated assumption.

Comment: @Arastas: The asker is looking for a generalisation or alternative to Takens’ theorem, not whether they can apply the known theorem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible.

If your dynamics is on one attractor, you can only learn about that attractor¹ from observing the dynamics. To see this, consider what would happen if you radically change the dynamics outside the immediate vicinity of the observed attractor, but keep the attractor identical: Your dynamics would not change the slightest, because your trajectory never ventures into the regions you changed anyway.

As a specific example consider a ball moving on some geography with two valleys. This is a textbook example of a bistable system. If I observe a ball oscillating in one valley, this tells me nothing about the geography outside that valley (or more precisely the regions the ball visits). I can completely remove the other valley, add further valleys, etc.: The ball would still oscillate in exactly the same manner.

---

¹ and its very close vicinity depending on the continuity assumptions you can make.

Comment: But the bot attractors are generated by the same differential equation. How is it possible that there is no information about the differential equation within the trajectory on one attractor

Comment: There is information about the differential equation, but only for the states you actually visit. More specifically, if your ODE is $\dot{x} = f(x)$, you only learn something about $f$ for $x$ on your attractor. Other values are never fed into $f$ when solving your dynamics. In particular, you can find $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that $f_1|_\mathcal{A}=f_2|_\mathcal{A}$ (with $\mathcal{A}$ being your attractor), but that considerably differ elsewhere.

Comment: As a remark, your example is not a chaotic attractor.

Comment: @Arastas: Sure, but the specification that the attractors may be chaotic doesn’t affect my answer. In fact, my point is that you cannot even say that there is a second attractor, let alone whether it’s chaotic.

Comment: I think you are right in general.